# Как выполнить свое событие первым до остальных?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Скажем есть блок и чужой скрипт всплывающего окна при клике по нему. Нужно что бы само написанное событие hover выполнилось до события hover из чужого скрипта. Как такое можно осуществить?

Comment: а что за события ?

Comment: Оно? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742610/attaching-jquery-event-handlers-so-that-they-are-triggered-first

Comment: А вот в виде плагина https://plugins.jquery.com/bind-first/

Comment: да это то что нужно. спасибо